Sporadic Issue in BPMN Workflow
There is a sporadic issue in the BPMN workflow running on Version "jBPM 5.4.0.Final," where the next node is not reliably created after task completion.
Here are the observations:

The task is completed without any issues, but the next node is intermittently not triggered.
The issue occurs randomly, functioning correctly most of the time, but failing under specific conditions.
There are no exceptions or errors recorded when the task completes.
The problem tends to manifest more frequently when tasks are being created and completed in rapid succession within the same process instance.

The issue appears to originate from the method shown below, where the flow fails to enter the if block. It seems that the "workItemId" retains the previous work-item ID of the process instance, causing the if block to be skipped and preventing the next node from being created.
Below is the code for reference
**org.jbpm.workflow.instance.node.WorkItemNodeInstance**

public void workItemCompleted(WorkItem workItem) {
        if ( workItemId == workItem.getId()
                || ( workItemId == -1 && getWorkItem().getId() == workItem.getId()) ) {
            removeEventListeners();
            triggerCompleted(workItem);
        }
}

Insights or recommendations for resolving this issue would be valuable.

Hi Maria, jBMN version 5.4.0.Final was released 12 years ago, so it's very unlikely to find someone who can support you in tackling this issue. Did you consider updating it to a newer version?

I can just agree with @Yeser Amer. Using jBPM 7 would increase rapidly the chances to get support from the community.

jBMN version 5.4.0.Final was released 12 years ago, so it's very unlikely to find someone who can support you in tackling this issue.
My suggestion is to update it at least to version 7.x, I would recommend considering moving to the upcoming Apache KIE 10.0.0 that holds jBMN (the latest  version)

Is it possible to migrate work-in-progress data from the "jBPM version 5.4.0.Final" task database to the jBPM version 7. x database?
Are there any migration scripts available for this process?
